# What is the EFI shell?

Tags: boot, bios, efi, vt-x

My BIOS offers me the option to launch an EFI shell, but I have no idea what that is. Does it allow me to turn on CPU flags like VT-x or something similar? Why would I want to use it?

Comment: Just check the manual to the motherboard.

Comment: [This presentation](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/Insyde_Using_the_UEFI_Shell.pdf) (PDF. 2010) has *"What is the UEFI 2.0 shell?"* (page 8).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The EFI Shell is a "shell" (think of a command prompt or a terminal shell)
that a (U)EFI BIOS can boot directly into (instead of your OS),
allowing control and scripting of many items including booting scenarios.

Installing an EFI shell in an "EFI System" partition (type EF00) formatted with a VFAT file system and properly named `shellx64.efi` for a 64-bit system will allow you to boot directly into it from your BIOS.

See [Basic Instructions for Using
the Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI)] (PDF)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/efi_instructions.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the better answer than mine. The only thing I would add is the shell looks like a mini-OS and not able to configure 'BIOS' type settings the OP was asking about.

Comment: why does it need to be properly named `shellx64.efi` - is there a default action to that locates the shell and makes it available on that (path)name?

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: What it can set does depend on your BIOS, but many do allow features to be adjusted that can't be from the general menu. 

The only way to know what it allows access to is to look.

Comment: As of 2023-06, the link is working.

Comment: @RobertWmRuedisueli, how might one evaluate the capabilities exposed via the shell?