# What is "launch efi shell from filesystem device" from the boot manager?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, usb, uefi

Im trying to boot my laptop from my USB Flash drive with its USB Legacy disabled and the internal Hard Drive has no Operating system (clean). After i entered the "launch efi shell from filesystem device" from the boot manager it brought me to a loading screen with windows 10 logo and below is "Automatic repairing" and "Diagnosing your PC". So what does it do? Will it boot my USB Flash drive that has windows 10 installer successfully?

Comment: The EFI Shell is a "shell" (think of a command prompt) that a (U)EFI "BIOS" can directly boot into (instead of your OS) allowing control and scripting of many items including booting scenarios,
Installing an EFI shell in an "EFI System" partition (type EF00) formatted with a vfat file system and properly named - "shellx64.efi" for a 64 bit system - will allow you to directly boot into it from your "BIOS".  We can try to recreate USB bootable media according to the link.  https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-bootable-media-uefi-support

Comment: Duplicated? https://superuser.com/questions/592854/what-is-the-efi-shell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the EFI shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/592854/what-is-the-efi-shell)